# Play sounds using Actionscript 3 file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This might be a very simple question, but it got me stumped.

I got a .wav file called blaster in my library (class name = blaster) and now I'm trying to play it using an external .as file.

I tried

```
public var blaster:Sound = new blaster;
```

and calling blaster using blaster.play(); in a function ahead, but it keeps giving this error:

Call to a possibly undefined method blaster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `new blaster;` to `new blaster();`, other than that everything looks fine to me, provided the ActionScript Linkage in symbol properties has been setup correctly.

Comment: Hmm strange, have you tried changing the format of the sound file to mp3 using Audacity or a similar program?  I used http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sound/ when I first used sound in Flash and it uses the same method as yours, only with an mp3 instead of a wav.

Comment: Ah found it, Actionscript apparently cant handle .wav files. Quickly changed the sound to something else, and it works as long as its an MP3. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, actually, it wasn't that... or at least, I just found out that the variable cant have the same name as the linkage.

Comment: Ah of course, I completely overlooked that!  Give it a try with the wav again if you like to be sure.